# Web API to get a list of all religions

Tags: web-services, rest

I am working for a health foundation. We are creating a great app to track everything related to nutrition, activity, milestones, etc. For the profile section, we need to add a list of all religions. Is there an API on the web to retrieve such a list?

Comment: Are you asking if such a web api exists, or if you should make a web service to do so, or if it would even be a good idea to make such a web service?  Its not clear.

Comment: It better include the FSM! http://www.venganza.org/

Comment: I tried to ask if such a web api exists. Thanks.

Comment: Tangentially related to @TrueWill's comments... there *is* no official list of religions. I sure hope you'll also add a "Not Listed" or "Other" option in case you miss something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An API would be too much to have. I suggest hardcode [the major religions in this list from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_religious_groups). (I don't think religions are created often enough to need an API :)

Comment: I am a very lazy developer :)

Comment: as am i. i even googled rubygems to see if there was a gem with a list of religions built into it.

Comment: oh i just found something. thank god (pun intended) for google.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that anything like this exists. [ProgrammableWeb](http://www.programmableweb.com/search/religion) has catalogued virtually every usable API.

Answer (score 0):

[This is the closest that I've found so far](http://www.guavastudios.com/religion-list.htm). Not exactly a web service but it'll do nicely for some easy copy and paste work, or parsing if you're *really* dedicated.